# How do I resize an Avatar image into a smaller one in a fixed header navbar using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need help about resize avatar image into a smaller one in a `fixed` header navbar. I created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/WbpNvg)** from *codepen.io*

When you scroll down on the page then the navbar to be a fixed. But i want to add a avatar in a navbar when scroll down like twitter. Anyone can help me here ?

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.globalHeader').scrollToFixed();
    $('.footer').scrollToFixed( {
        bottom: 0,
        limit: $('.footer').offset().top
    });
    var summaries = $('.summary');
    summaries.each(function(i) {
        var summary = $(summaries[i]);
        var next = summaries[i + 1];

        summary.scrollToFixed({
            marginTop: $('.globalHeader').outerHeight(true) + 10,
            limit: function() {
                var limit = 10;
                if (next) {
                    limit = $(next).offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true) - 10;
                } else {
                    limit = $('.footer').offset().top - $(this).outerHeight(true) - 10;
                }
                return limit;
            },
            zIndex: 0
        });
    });
    $('#sponsor').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: $('.globalHeader').outerHeight(true) + 10,
        limit: function() {
            var limit = $('.footer').offset().top - $('#sponsor').outerHeight(true) - 10;
            return limit;
        },
        minWidth: 1000,
        zIndex: 999,
        fixed: function() {  },
        dontCheckForPositionFixedSupport: true
    });

    $('#sponsor').bind('unfixed.ScrollToFixed', function() {
        if (window.console) console.log('sponsor preUnfixed');
    });
    $('#sponsor').bind('unfixed.ScrollToFixed', function() {
        if (window.console) console.log('sponsor unfixed');
        $(this).css('color', '');
        $('.globalHeader').trigger('unfixed.ScrollToFixed');
    });
    $('#sponsor').bind('fixed.ScrollToFixed', function() {
        if (window.console) console.log('sponsor fixed');
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        $('.globalHeader').trigger('fixed.ScrollToFixed');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.globalHeader {
  z-index: 90;
  background-color: #323949;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3f4858;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}
.globalHeader_in {
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 960px;
  width: 100%!important;
  max-width: 1580px;
  height: 52px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 15px;
  margin: auto;
}
.profile-kapak-alani {
    width:100%;
    height:385px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size:cover;
    border-bottom:1px solid #3f4858;
    background: #323949 url(icons/genis.png) repeat 0 0;
}
.profil-kapak-profil-resim {
    width:900px;
    height:385px;
    margin:0px auto;
    }
.profil-kapak {
    width:900px;
    height:385px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
.profil-kapak img {
    width:900px;
    }
.profil-ana-etki-alani{
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 52px 30px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
     border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -o-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    }
.kullanici-profil-fotografi-alani {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-110px;
    margin-left:30px;
    position:absolute;
    padding:8px;
    z-index:5;
    background-color: rgba(50, 57, 73, 1);
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset; 
    }
.kullanici-profil-fotografi-alani span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
}
.profil-fotografini-degistir {
    position:absolute;
    width:55px;
    height:35px;
    margin-top:-38px;
    margin-left:4px;
    }
.link-abonelik-takipci-fotograf-takip {
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   position:relative;
   border-bottom:1px solid #3f4858; 
   background-color: #323949;
   border-top:1px solid #3f4858;    
   box-shadow: 0 -7px 5px -6px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -7px 5px -6px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 -7px 5px -6px #000000;;
   -o-box-shadow:0 -7px 5px -6px #000000;;
    }
.la-t-f-t {
   width:900px;
   height:60px;
   margin:0px auto;
    }
.ll-p-t{
   float:right;
   width:630px;
   height:60px;
    }
.pay-t{
   float:left;
   width:88px;
   height:60px;
   padding-left:15px;
   padding-right:15px;
    }
.pay-t-t {
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#9aa2ae;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
   font-size:11px;  
   margin-top:10px;
   float:left;
   width:88px;
   text-align:center;
    }
.p-t-t-a{
    font-weight:bold;
   color:#9aa2ae;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
   font-size:18px;  
   text-align:center;
   margin-top:8px;
   float:left;
   width:88px;
    }
#navbar {

    position: absolute;
   width:100%;
  height:60px;
}
.main-content{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:red;
}
.content{
  margin:0px auto;
  width:900px;
  height:900px;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
}
.footer.scroll-to-fixed-fixed {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I feel like Frozen is literally everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the large background image, you can simply use `$(window).scroll()` to slow down the scrolling. You also need to set your content to `position: relative` so it sits above the overflowing background image (since it will scroll at a much slower rate). But your nav bar has a dynamically added `z-index:auto` which will then cause it to sit behind your content (probably from the plugin) so you'll have to use `!important` on your `#navbar`'s z-index:

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".profil-kapak").css({"top":(scrolled*0.7)+"px"});

});
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar {
   position: absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   z-index: 4 !important; //add, need to override the plugin
}

.main-content{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:red;
   position: relative; //add
}
```

For the mini profile look, you can set up the container in your nav bar set to `display: none` and do a simple fade in/out with the bigger one when the nav bar get's fixed:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mini-profile-wrapper">
   <div class="mini-profile-img">
      <img src="http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Frozen-Movie-poster-payoff-Wallpaper-HD1.jpg">
   </div>
   <p class="profile-name">John Doe</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mini-profile-wrapper{
   display: none;
   float: left;
}

.mini-profile-img{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 80px;
   padding: 5px 5px 0 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.mini-profile-img img{
   max-width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}

.mini-profile-wrapper .profile-name{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#FFF;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
   font-size:20px;  
}
```

**You can Use pre-existing JS function**

```
$('#navbar').bind('unfixed.ScrollToFixed', function() {
   ...
   $(".kullanici-profil-fotografi-alani").fadeIn();
   $(".mini-profile-wrapper").fadeOut();
});

$('#navbar').bind('fixed.ScrollToFixed', function() {
   ...
   $(".kullanici-profil-fotografi-alani").fadeOut();
   $(".mini-profile-wrapper").fadeIn();
});
```

## [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwpoBd)

Comment: @innovation I got the image to stick out at the top. Just needed to restructure the HTML a bit - added a new codepen

Comment: Yes I've seen dude. But there is a problem. If you do quickly down landing. The big picture is moving below navbar. But your answer is still true.

Comment: @innovation ok ill take a look when i get a chance

Comment: i need help can you help me Dear ?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is doing some interesting things in this case. The container #1 for the small avatar is in the navigation bar all the time in the same place. That avoids messing around with the placement of the avatar and any other outside elements.

The content of this container #1 is container #2 and has a given `height` and in its not-fixed state a `padding-top` of the same value. And because of the `overflow: hidden`, the inner content (avatar, texts) gets cut of.

As soon as the navigation bar gets fixed, the `padding-top` of container #2 is set from the `height` to 0, and thanks to a CSS `transition`, we have a nice animation. In addition, the big avatar get animated away.

**Conclusion:** Make the smaller version and place in a spot where you want. Keep this position all the time and just change its visibility. Can be the way described above, can also just be a simple `visibility: hidden`. Be creative. And then, when you fix your navigation, simply show the small avatar, and hide it, when its going to be unfixed.